# Creating a child window within a frame

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I'd like to create a frame window that can contain child windows, without using MDI which is way too complex for my needs.

So, I create a frame window CMainFrame derived from CFrameWnd and then a class Child derived from CWnd, with the following constructor:

```
Child::Child()
{
    CString strWndClass = AfxRegisterWndClass(CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW, 0, 0, 0);

    CWnd *cwnd = AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd;
    Create(strWndClass, "Title child", WS_CHILD, CRect(0, 0, 200, 200), cwnd, 0, NULL);
}
```

But when I create the Child window from the main frame:

```
void CMainFrame::Click()
{
    Child *child = new Child();
    child->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
}
```

nothing appears. Though, the creation of the child did not fail. What's the problem?

Comment: Did you implement WM_PAINT for your child window?

Comment: No. That's a good point. When I add the style WS_CAPTION at window creation, the child window does appear but its background is not painted. What are the required steps to have this window at least display as a normal one?

Comment: Create a MFC application with a CDialogView. Create the child in this view...

Comment: I created a CFormView, removed the dynamic creation part (otherwise I can't call its constructor) and called it from my handler. An ASSERT is triggered: ::IsWindow(m_hWnd) return FALSE. The fact is I didn't precise it was a child to my window frame. These forms are not supposed to be created by hand as I did, but there should be a trick to do it.

Comment: Why don't you want the dynamic construction, ise it? A view needs a frame and a document. Back to your original question. Your frame has a view? If so the view covers the complete area of the frame... you child may be covered.

Comment: As I said in my post, the goal is to avoid using MDI, so I have neither a view nor a document. Anyway, I created the window based on CDialog and the controls do appear but there are several problems (the focus is never set to the window, it's not repainted correctly and it can be moved over the frame toolbar).